# Error when stop editing a feature in ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, editing, network, error-999999

I want to make changes in a feature attribute table  that is an edge source of a Network dataset. In the next step, I need to rebuild the Network to make the changes take efect.

The problem is that, when I open the editor session and make changes in attribute table, then when I want to close the session the script crashes.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Network")

gdb = r"C:\GDB\NetworkGDB.gdb"
env.workspace = gdb
env.overwriteOutput = True

edt = arcpy.da.Editor(gdb)
edt.startEditing(False,False)
WHERE = '"OBJECTID_12" = 2'
direcao = "yes" #This value was set by another process that's indeppend on this one... Inclusive I tried a fixed value like in this example

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("Network_nd_roads",["OBJECTID_12","osm_oneway"],     WHERE) as cursor:
    for lin in cursor:
        txtLog = "Change value from " + lin[1] + " to " + direcao
        escreverArquivoLog(logFile,txtLog) #function to write a logfile
        lin[1] = direcao
        cursor.updateRow(lin)
        escreverArquivoLog(logFile,"Change suceed!!!")

escreverArquivoLog(logFile,u"Closing edition...")
edt.stopEditing(True) #-----HERE HAPPENS THE ERROR!!------
```

The error is:

> *File: C:\SCRIPT\Python\OneWayRules.py*
>
> *Message: RuntimeError: A network source with the specified name don't exist.*
>
> *ArcPy Message: ERROR 999999: Fail to execute function. User don't have permission to execute the operation. [N_1_Desc] An error happens
>   when executing (BuildNetwork).*

But as you can see, I dont call *BuildNetwork* function yet, I just make changes in the edige source of my Network.

------ UPDATE -------

As  blord-castillo says, I tryed to use *with* block in my edition and the *startOperation()*,*stopOperation()* inside this block, but the error occurs in **__exit__** Attribute. Folow my actual code:

```
with edt.startEditing() as ed:
    WHERE = '"OBJECTID_12" = 2'
        ed.startOperation ()
        with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(roadsLayer,["OBJECTID_12","osm_oneway"], WHERE) as cursor:
            for lin in cursor:
                txtLog = "Aterar o valor de " + lin[1] + " para " + direcao
                escreverArquivoLog(logFile,txtLog)
                lin[1] = "yes"
                cursor.updateRow(lin)
                escreverArquivoLog(logFile,"Suceed!!!")
        ed.stopOperation()
```

The error stil appearing in this code, on ***exit*** statement.

Comment: Have you tried checking out the NA license first?  `arcpy.CheckOutExtension('Network')`

Comment: Yes, this is checked out

Comment: I think Build Network is called when you close the edit session with a dirty areas in your network. You reference ```row[0]``` but I do not see where ```row``` is ever defined? Is "yes" a valid value for your evaluator for your network dataset (normally it is not)? Try putting ```edt.startOperation()``` before your cursor block and ```edt.stopOperation()``` after your cursor block. Alternately, try using a ```with``` block for your edit session instead of explicitly starting and stopping (```startOperation``` and ```stopOperation``` are built into the ```with``` block).

Comment: Post eddited, the _row[0]_ is a value of the FID I want to edit. The value "yes" is permited and used in other rows in this field. I will try the operation statement and see if it works...

Comment: -----Update----
Still occurring the _permission error_... but the _network sorce error_ stopped...

Comment: Since your error has changed, and before anyone offers and answer, is an ideal time to use the [edit] button to re-write your question to let us know precisely where you are stuck now.